# Calculating the sum of a column based on another column in another table in the field calculator of QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, summarizing, aggregate

I have a records table with site numbers and abundances of different species at that site (e.g. site 1 has 6 common bats and 13 pipistrellus bats).

[image]

I would like to sum total number (i.e. 6+13=19) at that site into another column within another table of a point shapefile locating the sites in some kind of expression used in the field calculator. Is this possible?

I have tried

```
aggregate( 'records', 'sum', "Abundance", "SiteNum")
```

but this has given me the same value (808) for every site in the new column of the point shapefile attribute table i.e. is ignoring the factor of site number.

Comment: Could you provide example data from the attribute table, as well as describe more detailed the feature types of records and sites? Also, have you had a look at the `aggregate`-expression of the field calculator?

Comment: @Erik I have edited my question. It now gives all sites the same value...

Comment: I guess the `sum` part should read something like  `...'sum("Abundance",group_by:="SiteNum")'...` - but to be honest I have no idea what the `aggregate`- expression should read then. Aggregate is like dark humor - not everyone gets it.

Comment: The field calculator doesn't seem to accept that string. Anything I have tried just gives all the sites the same value and ignore the factor.

Comment: You would have to incorporate it into the whole aggregate-function. See the description of the `sum`-expression.

Comment: I did put it into the aggregate-function `aggregate( 'records', 'sum("Abundance" ,group_by:="SiteNum")' , "Abundance" )` but it is invalid any way I try it

Comment: Ok, the problem is grabbing the created info to put it into the site-layer. Within the abundance-layer `sum(Abundance,SiteNum)` should work fine. So, what happens if we go with `aggregate('layernamefromthefieldcalc','max','sum(Abundance,SiteNum)')`? It is important that you use the layername with which the abundance-layer is referenced under in the field calculator (point "map layer") - the simple `'records'` wont work most likely.

Comment: 'records' is the layer name that the abundance data is referenced. It came back with `NULL`, but then I tried `aggregate('records','max', "Abundance","SiteNum")` and it just gave me the same number for each site again just this time it was the maximum abundance noted not the sum/total... any way I try it doesn't respond to the factor of site number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to `sum` the `"Abundance"` grouped by `"SiteNum"` and place the results in `another_table` with a common `ID`?

The clue is in `relation_aggregate()`.  More info: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions and in the expression-builder

First, you have to define a relation: Project > properties > relations.

- Set the relation with 'records' as child and 'another_layer' as parent.
- Give the relation a name.  This name you need in the `relation_aggregate()`

  `relation_aggregate( 
      relation:= 'name', 
      aggregate:= 'sum', 
      expression:= "Abundance"
      )`

Comment: It can be so easy.

Comment: sometimes :-).  But it is really hard to understand all the possibilities of the aggregate-functions...

Comment: ok, thank you, I will give it a go!

Comment: It worked. Thank you!!

Comment: I edited my answer with more info about child and parent

Comment: Which file-format is used to store the records?  Which are the fieldproperties of 'SiteNum'?  Are there unexpected spaces in the data?  The same questions has to be asked for the other layer.